# Запись данных в бд PostgreSQL на любом языке

Tags: postgresql

В базе данных PostgreSQL допускается запись данных на любых языках? Например, на английском, русском и грузинском языках одновременно.
И еще, как сделать, чтобы в одной базе данных хранить так: одна таблица с русским языком, другая -- с грузинским, третья с английским одновременно?

Comment: PostgreSQL умеет работать юникодом, так что проблем с текстом на разных языках быть не должно. Ну а отдельные таблицы для разных языков сделать - это уже логика приложения, можно и в одну таблицу все сложить и добавить поле с признаком языка, тут уже от вас зависит как именно делать, вариантов много. И тут еще почитайте на всякий случай http://stackoverflow.com/q/1245217/5796587

Comment: Спасибо. Вот то, что нужно. Был не уверен в выборе решения в пользу PostgreSQL, после вашего замечания утвердился в своем решении.

Comment: @rdorn отвеееет.

Comment: @andreycha да это гуглится меньше чем за минуту, в ответ перенес конечно, но как-то для полноценного ответа не серьезно что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенес из комментариев.

PostgreSQL умеет работать юникодом, так что проблем с текстом на разных языках быть не должно. Ну а отдельные таблицы для разных языков сделать - это уже логика приложения, можно и в одну таблицу все сложить и добавить поле с признаком языка, тут уже от вас зависит как именно делать, вариантов много.

И еще почитайте на всякий случай [**тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1245217/5796587) и [**тут**](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200404291220.01457.josh@agliodbs.com)